# Angular Select not opening until other element gets clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 6 with Material components.
Since changing my code (I am not sure when this started happening) my select elements act very weird.

[Video of weird behavior](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qMlfgCPtwxeCNhfw3iC4XjGELnD6H1UB/view)

As you can see, the select boxes for the addresses do not open until I click the mat-autocomplete in the top. I could also click another element, that will also cause the selects to open.

What could be causing this? I really have no clue.

```
      <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <!--                <input matInput placeholder="{{ 'mainapp.shipment.pickupaddress' | translate }}"
                               attr.aria-label="{{ 'mainapp.shipment.pickupaddress' | translate }}" [matAutocomplete]="auto_p"
                               formControlName="address_from"
                        >
                        <mat-autocomplete #auto_p="matAutocomplete" autoActiveFirstOption [displayWith]="displayAddress">
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let pickup of filteredAddresses_pickup | async" [value]="pickup">
                            <span>{{pickup.name}}, {{pickup.postalcode}}, {{pickup.country}}</span>
                          </mat-option>
                        </mat-autocomplete>-->
        <mat-label>{{ 'mainapp.shipment.pickupaddress' | translate }}</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="address_from">
          <!--<mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
            {{food.viewValue}}
          </mat-option>-->
          <mat-option value="no_change" *ngIf="shipment_id">{{ 'mainapp.shipment.address_selector.no_change' | translate }}</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="update" *ngIf="shipment_id" (click)="openAddAddressDialog('from', fromAddress)">{{ 'mainapp.shipment.address_selector.update' | translate }}</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="new" (click)="openAddAddressDialog('from')">{{ 'mainapp.shipment.address_selector.new' | translate }}</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="new_entered" [ngClass]="addressFromSelected ? 'none': 'hide_element'">{{addressFromSelectedLabel}}</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="visiting_address">{{ 'mainapp.shipment.address_selector.visiting_address' | translate }}</mat-option>
          <mat-optgroup label="Recent addresses">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let address of _addresses | async" [value]="address">
              {{ displayAddress(address) }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-optgroup>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Show your TS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same `formControlName` for multiple elements.
Watch the comments! I removed a lot of code for visibility.

```html
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
   <input matInput placeholder="{{ 'mainapp.shipment.pickupaddress' | translate }}"
   attr.aria-label="{{ 'mainapp.shipment.pickupaddress' | translate }}" [matAutocomplete]="auto_p"
   formControlName="address_from" />// This is address_from
   <mat-label>{{ 'mainapp.shipment.pickupaddress' | translate }}</mat-label>
   <mat-select formControlName="address_from">
      // and this address_from needs to be something different
      <mat-option value="visiting_address">{{ 'mainapp.shipment.address_selector.visiting_address' | translate }}</mat-option>
      <mat-optgroup label="Recent addresses">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let address of _addresses | async" [value]="address">
         {{ displayAddress(address) }}
         </mat-option>
      </mat-optgroup>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Nope, I am not using a ngFor, the options are static here. I do use ngx-translate for the text

Comment: I didn't mean an ngFor just a regular html for. Ill update my answer.